# CUSTOM CRON EXPRESSION

Tags: cron

Really Appreciatable if anyone give solution for the below query

Cron Expression for Running a job every 2 hours start at 8.05 am ends at 10.05 PM ?

Comment: Here you go: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/crontab.htm

Comment: @Kometen.....Thank you so much.... i have tried cron expression for every 2 hours between 8 to 10 (0 08-22/2 * * * )

Comment: but i dont know how to starts with 8.05 ..........please help me out on this

Comment: If 8.05 is five minutes past then look where to configure minutes. It's not that hard.

Comment: Kindly Confirm , (05 08-22/2 * * * ) is this correct ?

Comment: This site is for programming related questions, this question is not. And it assumes you have put some effort into trying to solve it your self.